# Uncaught Error: Minified exception occurred [Facebook Login]

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to integrate my website with facebook login. I have followed all the documentation provided by Facebook (Quick Start). Here is my code

```
function init() {   
    function checkLoginState() {
      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          if(response.status=="connected"){
            var fbUser = response.authResponse.userID;
            var fbAccess = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            var data = new FormData();
            data.append('fbUser',fbUser);
            data.append('fbAccess',fbAccess);
            callAjax('dologinfacebook',data);
          }
      });
    }
    checkLoginState();
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'myappid',
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v3.0'
  });

  init();
};

(function(d, s, id){
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

It works great, I receive the response without any problem but at the end of my console. I receive this following error.

```
B5sq21HbPZ9.js:44 Uncaught Error: Minified exception occurred; use the non-minified dev environment for the full error message and additional helpful warnings.
    at a (B5sq21HbPZ9.js:44)
    at a (B5sq21HbPZ9.js:121)
    at x (B5sq21HbPZ9.js:193)
    at Object.b.post [as log] (B5sq21HbPZ9.js:193)
    at a.logVital (B5sq21HbPZ9.js:219)
    at B5sq21HbPZ9.js:293
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at IntersectionObserver.f.threshold (B5sq21HbPZ9.js:293)
```

Anyone can suggest me what should I do to remove this following error? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

It is a known bug: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1337180213092053/

Subscribe to it if you want to know when it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

There is a temporary solution for you, if you can have a separate link/button to logout.
You can logout from this separate button using facebook api like:-

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.

      FB.logout(function(response) {
   //Person is now logged out    
});   
    } 
    });
```

And you can turn off auto logout link from facebook login button like this data-auto-logout-link="false":-

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-width="10" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-scope="email,public_profile" data-button-type="continue_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true" data-use-continue-as="true" >


<div class="fb-login-button" data-width="10" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-scope="email,public_profile" data-button-type="continue_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="true" >
```